# mariaDB master/slave do not replicate

Tags: linux, mariadb, replication

I'm having problems creating an infrastructure for mariaDB, master/slave.

I followed this guide:
https://hevodata.com/learn/mariadb-replication-easy-steps/

everything seems to have gone well until the end.

but when I create something on the master, it doesn't copy to the slave.

I noticed that using
show slave status\G;

the slave copies Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 1169 exactly

as it sits on the master and sees the changes

Relay_Log_Space: 1528

but I can't find anything on the slave database, which I created on the master.

could anyone help me?

If you need further information, I remain available, but I practically have the same settings as in the guide, in the link left above.

A thousand thanks

Comment: Somebody probably can help you - just not on SO. SO is a Q/A site for programming and software development related questions and your question is about database operations instead. The DBA sister-site of SO can help you in finding a solution to your problem.

Comment: i understant, thx for the answer

Comment: The size of and position in the Primary's binlog and the Replica's relay log are rarely the same.  Don't worry.  (And, yes, dba.stackexchange.com is better for admin questions.)